# Wrap the code to translate with wordpress/poedit?

Tags: wordpress, poedit

Current I have WP code like this. I need to make it translateable by poedit. How do I wrap the code to make it work? Im not sure which method is use for this case. Some thing like:

```
<?php my_e( 'Total sales' ); ?> or __('Total sales', 'my')
```

This is the code. I need to translate ["**Sales amount**"], ["**Number of sales**"]

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
$date = $result->formatted_post_date;
$statistics[$date]["Sales amount"] += $wp_list_table->column_total_sales($result->ID);
$statistics[$date]["Number of sales"]++;
$statistics[$date]["date"] = $date;
$max_number_of_sales = max(array($max_number_of_sales,$statistics[$date]["Number of sales"] ));  }
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `__('string','textdomain')` to assign a translated string to some variable. And `_e('string','textdomain')` to echo a translated string. See [I18n_for_WordPress_Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Two observations:

- you'll not be able to translate array keys, see [php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- what you're doing seems wrong. I'd do it like:

```
$sales_amount = 0;
$sales_number = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $sales_amount += $wp_list_table->column_total_sales($result->ID);
    $sales_number++;
    $date = $result->formatted_post_date;
    $statistics[$date]["sales_amount"] = $sales_amount;
    $statistics[$date]["sales_number"] = $sales_number;
}
echo __( 'Sales Amount', 'my' ) . $sales_amount;
```

Comment: Can I do something like this? 

`$title_setting =  __( 'Settings');
$title_general =  __( 'General');
$title_management = __( 'Management');
$title_voucher =  __( 'Manage Vouchers');
$title_tool =   __( 'Tools');
$title_addon =   __( 'Add-on');`

Comment: Seems correct and only missing the locale string `__('text', 'locale');`